# How can i make a moving button in GWT， so that users can move it to anywhere they want?

Tags: gwt

I just want to make a moving button , Is there a way to do that in GWT? Thanks in advance.

BS

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the help section on [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried? Please post some code and tell us what is not working or which part you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, you can use a DialogBox to display your button. DialogBox can be moved around, but you will need to display something in a Caption that is used for dragging.

Another option is to use PopupPanel. It can be completely invisible (no Caption), but you will have to implement dragging functionality on your own. The advantage is that a PopupPanel floats on top of all the other layers in your UI.

Finally, you can simply add dragging functionality to a regular button. Just remember to check for the boundaries so that a user cannot drag your button outside of the visible browser area - or obscure some important elements of the UI.